# Keras Tuner - tunning multiple same parameter

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've build my model and it works if I tune only one variable and do not repeat it over the other layers. For example, tune `unit` only in one layer works. Like my code below, I'm tring to tune multiple `units` and it doesn't work.

```py
def model_builder(hp):
  model = keras.Sequential()

  # Tune the number of units in the first Dense layer
  hp_units_1 = hp.Int('units_1', min_value=32, max_value=512, step=32)
  model.add(keras.layers.Dense(
      units=hp_units_1, 
      input_dim=7,
      activation='relu'))


  hp_units_2 = hp.Int('units_2', min_value=32, max_value=512, step=32)
  model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=hp_units_2 , activation='relu'))
  model.add(keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='sigmoid'))

  # Tune the learning rate for the optimizer
  # Choose an optimal value from 0.01, 0.001, or 0.0001
  hp_learning_rate = hp.Choice('learning_rate', values=[1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4])

  model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=hp_learning_rate),
                loss=keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
                metrics=['mse'])

  return model
```

Even though i'm using `_1` so to not repear the key, it throws an error.

```
Invalid model 0/5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kerastuner/engine/hypermodel.py", line 104, in build
    model = self.hypermodel.build(hp)
  File "<ipython-input-19-f964baafcc40>", line 5, in model_builder
    hp_units = hp.Int('units_1', min_value=32, max_value=512, step=32)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kerastuner/engine/hyperparameters.py", line 744, in Int
    return self._retrieve(hp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kerastuner/engine/hyperparameters.py", line 625, in _retrieve
    return self.values[hp.name]
KeyError: 'units_1'
```

Comment: Your error shows `hp_units = hp.Int()` while your code reads `hp_units_1 = hp.Int()`.

Answer (score 2):

In the end, maybe due to how Colab saves the runtime, it was kind of using the old one with new keywords (sounds realy strange though).

So to solve this I had to add the parameter `overwrite=True` to my tuner:

```py
tuner = kt.Hyperband(model_builder,
                     objective='val_loss',
                     max_epochs=10,
                     factor=3,
                     overwrite=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error could be because of the variables defined as part of building the model. You can probably define the variable before you start building the model as follows and check the results:

```
def model_builder(hp):
  hp_units_1 = hp.Int('units_1', min_value=32, max_value=512, step=32)
  hp_units_2 = hp.Int('units_2', min_value=32, max_value=512, step=32)
  # Tune the learning rate for the optimizer
  # Choose an optimal value from 0.01, 0.001, or 0.0001
  hp_learning_rate = hp.Choice('learning_rate', values=[1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4])
  model = keras.Sequential()      
  model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=hp_units_1, input_dim=7, activation='relu'))     
  model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=hp_units_2 , activation='relu'))
  model.add(keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='sigmoid'))
  model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=hp_learning_rate),
                loss=keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
                metrics=['mse'])

  return model
```